# Error using kableExtra collapse_rows with non-unique values in non-collapsed column

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

I'm using Rmarkdown to create a PDF containing tables and using `kableExtra::collapse_rows`. I'm getting an error upon knitting when my non-collapsed columns have repeated values.

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r}
library(magrittr)
library(knitr) 
library(kableExtra) 

# Build data with repeated values in last column
dat1 <- data.frame(x = c(rep("First",times=4),rep("Second",times=3)),
                   y = c(rep(4,times=4),rep(3,times=3)),
                   z = c("det1","det2","det2","det3","det4","det5","det5"),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# This works fine:
dat1 %>%
  kable(format="latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
````

[image]

```
# Throws an error when I try to collapse rows of first two columns:
dat1 %>%
  kable(format="latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names=FALSE) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2)
```

The error message I get is:

> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>
> `<recently read>` \endtemplate
>
> l.169 First &\vphantom{1} 4 & det2 &
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43

````
# Change up the data so last column has all unique values:
dat2 <- dat1
dat2$z <- c("det1","det2","det3","det4","det5","det6","det7")

# Works fine:
dat2 %>%
  kable(format="latex", booktabs = TRUE, row.names=FALSE) %>%   
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2)
```
````

[image]

The situation I'm working in requires items in the last column be allowed to repeat, so I'd like to be able to produce a nice version of it with the rows for the first two columns collapsed. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Klone I can't remember what I did to get around this before, but running it now does seem to work for me. Versions I'm currently running:
R: 4.0.0
RStudio: 1.2.5042
basic-miktex: 2.9.7386
knitr_1.28
kableExtra_1.1.0

Comment: @Klone if you have an old version of Pandoc sitting around, try uninstalling that as well. I don't think it's needed with newer versions of other packages.

Comment: I have updated mactex (I am macos), rstudio, all R and latex packages and the option `valign` is not generating an error now ... but is not working, the alignment is not properly made

Comment: I did a reprex that you can find there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62419547/kable-collapse-rows-and-booktabs-no-alignement-to-the-top